# How to convert props.children to string in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I want to convert react children to string.
In the below example I am passing div, h2 and p as children to Example in Exampleclass. when I call props.children in Example it returns an array but I need a props.children in the string format so that I can use it in dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Example from "./example";
export default class Exampleclass extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>in class</p>
        <Example> // passing div, h2 and p as children to Example
          <div>
          <h2>function</h2>
          <p>function</p>
          </div>
        </Example>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
import React from "react";

export default function example(props) {
  console.log("child", props.children); // returns array  but i need <div><h2>function</h2><p>function</p></div> here

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `${props.children}` }} />;    // returns [object Object]

}
```

Comment: Why you need to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML and no return props.children?

Comment: There is a high likelihood you are using React incorrectly. There are better ways to manipulate the DOM with React.

Comment: if you need to convert array to string then `array.toString()` but waht you are doing does not make seance coz alot of irrelevant things to the user are included in the props you need to check what you need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be difficult to transform `children` object into some kind of a flat string with a JSX-a-like structure. `children` is a complex object with a lot of nested fields. You would have to convert it firstly to an *array*, then iterate over it, probably recursively, pick correct props and so on.

However you could pass your children **not** as a *children*, but as a separate prop.

```js
const Child = ({ child }) => {
   return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: child }} />;
};

const App = () => {
  const data = `
     <div>
        <h2>function</h2>
        <p>function</p>
     </div>
  `;

  return <Child child={data} />
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**: You could, however, use `renderToStaticMarkup` function, but it will render only pure *html* (it will compile components into html). In your example you are passing only html elements so I guess it would be okey.

```
const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(children);

return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: markup }} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`react-children-utilities`](https://github.com/fernandopasik/react-children-utilities) has a function, [`onlyText`](https://github.com/fernandopasik/react-children-utilities/blob/main/docs/only-text.md), that does this.

It uses `React.Children.toArray(children).reduce` then recursively loops through children, concatenating a string made up of every child and nested child that is a string or a number, skipping everything else.

---

**Disclaimer**: be aware that if your component's children includes components with props or attributes that behave like children when rendered, but aren't actually in the React elements as `children`, they'll be omitted.

For example, if you're trying to approximate the text that tools like screen readers or search engine bots would read on focusing an element, this approach will skip text in attributes like `alt`, `label` or `value` that such tools might include. It also won't do things like collapse whitespace.

---

Since `onlyText` is a pretty simple function, I'd suggest looking at its implementation (linked above) and consider writing your own variant that adds in any other relevant attributes that your use case needs which would otherwise be skipped.